# How to JOIN using LIKE '<column>%'

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-like, postgresql-9.4

I have a list of items, each of which has a category code:

```
id | name       | category_code
---+------------+--------------
11 | 'Cookies'  | '43040'
53 | 'Potatoes' | '43100'
```

These category codes work hierarchically, for example the beginning `43` might mean food, the ending `04` pastry or the ending `10` root vegetables.

I also have a table of the names of the codes like so:

```
code    | name
--------+------------------------------------
'4304'  | 'Food -> Pastery'
'43040' | 'Food -> Pastery -> Cookie'
'43100' | 'Food -> Root Vegetables -> Potato'
```

These codes and the system is not designed by me, so I can't influence it. It is what it is.

Now the problem is, I have a mapping of keywords to the codes, such as:

```
id | key       | code
---+-----------+--------
22 | 'cookie'  | '43040'
23 | 'pastery' | '4304'
24 | 'cake'    | '43042'
```

And I need to perform search based on these keywords. What I tried so far:

```
SELECT item.id, item.name, category.code, category.name
FROM item
LEFT JOIN category ON category.code = item.category_code
LEFT JOIN keyword ON keyword.code = category.code
WHERE LOWER(keyword.key) = ANY(ARRAY['pastery', 'root']);
```

But the problem appears on the middle like `JOIN category ON category.code = item.category_code` because items always have the full code of the length five, but there are main categories for codes like `4304` and keywords matching to them.

I would need to perform a join with `LIKE` and `%`, ideally something like this:

```
SELECT item.id, item.name, category.code, category.name
FROM item
LEFT JOIN category ON (category.code + '%') LIKE item.category_code
LEFT JOIN keyword ON keyword.code = category.code
WHERE LOWER(keyword.key) = ANY(ARRAY['pastery', 'root']);
```

But obviously `(category.code + '%')` is not supported. How can I achieve this goal in other ways?

Comment: may be should you use `LPAD` function to prefix '0'. `LEFT JOIN category ON LPAD(category.code, 5, '0') = item.category_code`

Comment: `category ON (category.code + '%') LIKE item.category_code`
should read `category ON category.code LIKE item.category_code + '%'`

Comment: @Frode `'123' LIKE '1234%'` is not true while `'123%' LIKE '1234'` is.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Not in T-SQL AFAIK. Maybe % is used as a wildcard in other DB-systems, I dont know. Try item.category_code LIKE category.code + '%', then

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the postgresql tag in your question. My bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want.  The `like` is in the wrong order:

```
SELECT i.id, i.name, c.code, c.name
FROM item i LEFT JOIN
     category c
     ON  i.category_code like c.code || '%' LEFT JOIN
     keyword k
     ON k.code = c.code
WHERE LOWER(keyword.key) = ANY(ARRAY['pastery', 'root']);
```

Comment: Thank you *very*, *very* much! I had no idea you could concenate strings like this, and didn't even think of switching the order. Thanks, you saved me! :)